# ¿Por qué la palabra "sutil" es aguda?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, acentuación

[**Sutil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YqUtnyM) es

> Del lat. *subtīlis*.
>   1. adj. Delgado, delicado, tenue.
>   2. adj. Agudo, perspicaz, ingenioso.

y es **aguda** (acento en la última sílaba, sin tilde porque no acaba en "n", "s" o vocal).

Las otras palabras que recoge el diccionario de la lengua con la misma terminación: [**útil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bCSFzkP%7CbCTJISY), [**inútil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M1HoNHK), [**fútil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=If2oY1t) e [**inconsútil**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LIrx4hr) son todas **llanas** (acento en la penúltima sílaba, con tilde porque no acaban en "n", "s" o vocal).

¿Por qué **sutil** es diferente (aguda)?

Comment: ¿Será porque viene más directamente del francés subtil? http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=subtile

Comment: Lo que más me llama la atención es la diferencia entre **sutil** y **fútil**

Comment: La terminación es igual, pero no la raíz, así que no veo el problema, pero doy mi voto por que aprendí la palabra "inconsútil".

Comment: @fedorqui no podría ser del Frances ya que el Frances no tiene [acento léxico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) y, en todo caso, la palabra *subtil* [se pronuncia](https://www.howtopronounce.com/french/subtil/) con una especia de acento tanto en la primera como en la ultima silaba (o sea, sin acento especial).

Comment: @terdon qué bien visto, olvidé esta multiacentuación del francés :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La respuesta te la da la propia RAE en la grafía de las palabras latinas:

- en *subt**ī**lis*, lo que hay sobre la primera «i» es un [macrón](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macr%C3%B3n), que en latín moderno se usa para marcar las vocales largas;
- por el contrario, en *ut**ĭ**lis* y demás contraejemplos que has puesto, la «i» está marcada con un [acento breve](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breve_(signo_diacr%C3%ADtico)), que indica que es una vocal breve.

En latín, las [normas de acentuación](https://linguaeantiquae.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/normas-de-acentuacion/) dicen que:

> - Son llanas las palabras cuya penúltima sílaba es larga.
> - Son esdrújulas las palabras cuya penúltima sílaba es breve.
>
> Las vocales pueden ser largas (-) o breves(˘) por naturaleza.
>
> - Una sílaba es larga por naturaleza cuando contiene una vocal larga o un diptongo.
> - Una sílaba es larga por posición si contiene una vocal breve cerrada, es decir, seguida de dos o más consonantes, así como de z (=cs) y z (=ds).
> - Una sílaba es breve cuando termina por vocal breve.

Atendiendo a lo anterior, **de todas las palabras que has puesto, *sutil* es la única que en latín tenía el acento en la «i»; todas las demás lo tenían en la «u» de la sílaba precedente**. Por ese motivo, hoy ***sutil*** es aguda, y las demás llanas.